# VS 2012 CodeCoverage tool issue

Tags: c#, code-coverage

I have a simple console app. Using some dlls, I want to do the code coverage for those dlls using VS 2012 `CodeCoverage.exe`.

When I am registering my executable to the a session, its not capturing anything, but without the session I am able to get the coverage file.

Can anyone tell me what can be the issue? I am attaching the syntax that I used in VS 2012 cmd in admin mode to use the tool.

```
1.cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools
2.CodeCoverage.exe register /session:MySession /force "C:\Users\Desktop\trial\trialLibrary\trialClass\bin\Debug\trialClass.exe"
3.CodeCoverage.exe collect /session:MySession /output:MyResult.coverage
```

Note: When I am trying to shut down the session it throws an error

```
A session named MySession does not exist or access is denied
```

I tried to analyze the issue using the command

```
CodeCoverage.exe analyze /output:.\coverage.xml /include_skipped_functions /include_skipped_modules MyResult.coverage
```

but the generated `coverage.xml` file is empty.

Please help me.

Comment: Where did you see documentation for the `register` switch? I don't see it in the usage on notes. Same for `/force`. Is that something that worked in an earlier version of Visual Studio?

What happens if you do `CodeCoverage.exe collect /output:MyResult.coverage "C:\Users\Desktop\trial\trialLibrary\trialClass\bin\Debug\trialClass.exe"`?

Comment: You can also try using `/verbose` in your collect call.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the CodeCoverage.exe command line ARGUMENTS?  I cannot find them on msdn.